# Function to escape python strings doesn't work as intended

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to create a function that lets the user input some sort of string and then have the function neutralize control characters such as "\n" via the replacement function. E.g. you put in "\n" and the replacement function puts "\\n" instead of "\n" so you end up having "\n" printed just without the actual function.

I thought of something like:

```
print("Input your string:")
Inpt = input()
def escape_strings(Inpt):
    print(Inpt.replace("\\","\\\\").replace("\"","\\\'").replace("\'","\\\'").replace("\n","\\n"))

escape_strings(Inpt)
```

The problem is that it doesn't print the character that I want, but rather the actual replacement character. I know that you can also do this via the return statement but would that help in any way?

Comment: Does `print(input())` print the thing that you want?  Can you give an example of an input with a desired output, either in terms of Python string literals, or in terms of what you'd expect to see at the console?  (Those will be two different things, so be clear about what you're expecting to see where!)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show example input and output. Then explain how the output differs from what you want.

Comment: Another thing to try: `print(repr(input()))`.  I'm still not clear on exactly what it is you're trying to produce, but I suspect that either the string itself or its `repr` is pretty close...

Comment: When you see the function as a black box, I wanted to put in a string, for example "This is a great \n day" and have the control character be printed but  without any actual effect.

Comment: From what I can tell your code should do exactly as you describe. What problem did you encounter? Please give an example.

Comment: You are right. The problem I think lies in the fact that I use console input via the input function where no control characters have any effect

Comment: I just tested it and its the case.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? Escape sequences aren't processed in user input, so you don't need to escape them.

Comment: "I use console input via the input function where no control characters have any effect" That's not exactly true. The issue is most likely that as soon as you hit Enter, `input()` takes the input that you typed up to that point and returns it. There is no way to get a newline character in the middle of using `input()`.

Comment: Try `"This is a line.\nThis is another line.".replace("\n", "\\n")` to see that replace works exactly how you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. As of yet I have next to no knowledge in Python so that was the only explanation I could find.